# How to hide column from gridview on edit click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

"I m using asp.net gridview,when user clicks on edit button the dropdownlist column should get hide.what should i do to make it hide? I have attached the code below.The gridview contains students data and gridview will display records according to the classwise data selected by the user.i have tried on OnRowDataBound to hide the column but its not working for me.Is there any way where i can hide particular column OnRowEditing event"

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="id"  
                    CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" 
                    EmptyDataText="No Record Found....."    
  onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                 onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"  
                    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
  ForeColor="#333333" 
                    GridLines="None" 
  OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" 
  AllowPaging="true" >

            <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" />                       
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" 
  ForeColor="#284775" 
   />
             <Columns>                                         


               <asp:TemplateField>                      
               <ItemTemplate>            
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server"/>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>   

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr.No">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" 
    Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>     

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ack">
                        <ItemTemplate>


                                 <edititemtemplate>
                                     <asp:DropDownList 
              ID="Drpacknowledgement" AutoPostBack="True"

     onselectedindexchanged="Drpacknowledgement_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   runat="server">                                
                        <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Received</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Reject</asp:ListItem>                               
                        </asp:DropDownList>

                              </edititemtemplate>


                        </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Update">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB1" runat="server" 
  CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>                           
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB2" runat="server" 
   CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB3" runat="server" 
   CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>                          
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                  </Columns>



             </asp:GridView>  


   Codebehind:
   protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, 
   GridViewEditEventArgs 
   e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Id = 
            GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            ViewState["Id"] = Id;
            EditRecord();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Rowcommand for button click.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/%2FTips%2F564619%2FExample-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="id"  
                        CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" 
                        EmptyDataText="No Record Found....."    
      onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                     onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"  
                        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
      ForeColor="#333333" 
                        GridLines="None" 
      OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" 
       OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
      AllowPaging="true" >

                <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" />                       
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" 
      ForeColor="#284775" 
       />

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Update">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"
          CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>                           
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB2" runat="server" 
           CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LkB3" runat="server" 
           CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                            </EditItemTemplate>                          
                          </asp:TemplateField>


     protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
      if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
    //do your stuff here
 GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this will do the trick

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.EditIndex > -1)
            GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        else
            GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = true;
    }
```